# Eliminate white space beside background image

Tags: css

I have an element with a background image set to these properties:

```
#background-element {
   background: url("../background.jpg") top right no-repeat;
   background-position: right -350px top;
}
```

[image]
I have it positioned to the top right of the screen and offset -350px to align the image for better flow with the content.

It works and looks great until the view port gets to a certain size and then I get white space on the left side of screen.

I don't want to use `background-size: cover;` because I don't want the image to scale down as the view port size shrinks.

What can I do to keep the image pegged to the right, offest by -350px, and eliminate the white space as the view port gets past a certain width.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or some way that we can actually *SEE* the problem? The working code would be better...

Comment: @BryceHowitson the code in the post is all that I am currently using. added a screenshot of what is happening.

Comment: That's the only background image code but it's hard to debug if we can't reproduce the issue. What's the parent's CSS code doing for example?

Comment: Replace #background-element with body and that is literally the only code to style the background.

Comment: Can you put up a working snippet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The white space comes from the background color behind the image showing through.

If you had `body {background-color: green}` the space at the side would be green. You've moved the image -350 pixels to the right of the element (the same as `left 350px` and told the image not to repeat. So when the screen is wider than image width - 350px you'll get the color behind the image.

If you want the image to scale you'll have to use a `background-size` property like `cover`. If the image should not scale at some point. Then you would use a Media Query to say specify that.

```
/* normal */
#background-element {
   background: url("../background.jpg") top right no-repeat;
   background-position: right -350px top;
   background-size: cover;
}

/* if the screen is smaller than 600px then do this */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   #background-element {
      background-size: 100%;
   }
}
```

Comment: This was almost spot on. I changed the media query breakpoint to 1600px and changed background-size to cover and removed the -350px offset. and now the image stays pegged to the right and no more white space on a larger screen.